# Python Pandas reordering table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in pandas that looks like this:

```
ID     TIME         A            B            C
1      ddmmyy   value_of_A1   value_of_B1  value_of_C1
2      ddmmyy   value_of_A2   value_of_B2  value_of_C2
3      ddmmyy   value_of_A3   value_of_B3  value_of_C3
```

and I want to make it into a dataframe that looks like this:

```
ID     TIME       TYPE       VALUE
1      ddmmyy      A      value_of_A1
1      ddmmyy      B      value_of_B1
1      ddmmyy      C      value_of_C1
2      ddmmyy      A      value_of_A2
2      ddmmyy      B      value_of_B2
2      ddmmyy      C      value_of_C2
3      ddmmyy      A      value_of_A3
3      ddmmyy      B      value_of_B3
3      ddmmyy      C      value_of_C3
```

how can I do it using pandas and python?

thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.set_index(['ID','TIME']).stack().reset_index().rename(columns={'level_2':'TYPE',0:'VALUE'})
```

Output:

```
   ID    TIME TYPE        VALUE
0   1  ddmmyy    A  value_of_A1
1   1  ddmmyy    B  value_of_B1
2   1  ddmmyy    C  value_of_C1
3   2  ddmmyy    A  value_of_A2
4   2  ddmmyy    B  value_of_B2
5   2  ddmmyy    C  value_of_C2
6   3  ddmmyy    A  value_of_A3
7   3  ddmmyy    B  value_of_B3
8   3  ddmmyy    C  value_of_C3
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) with [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['ID','TIME'], var_name='TYPE', value_name='VALUE')
       .sort_values(['ID','TYPE'])
print (df)
   ID    TIME TYPE        VALUE
0   1  ddmmyy    A  value_of_A1
3   1  ddmmyy    B  value_of_B1
6   1  ddmmyy    C  value_of_C1
1   2  ddmmyy    A  value_of_A2
4   2  ddmmyy    B  value_of_B2
7   2  ddmmyy    C  value_of_C2
2   3  ddmmyy    A  value_of_A3
5   3  ddmmyy    B  value_of_B3
8   3  ddmmyy    C  value_of_C3
```

Alternative:

```
df = df.rename_axis(['TYPE'], axis=1)
       .set_index(['ID','TIME'])
       .stack()
       .reset_index(name='VALUE')

print (df)
   ID    TIME TYPE        VALUE
0   1  ddmmyy    A  value_of_A1
1   1  ddmmyy    B  value_of_B1
2   1  ddmmyy    C  value_of_C1
3   2  ddmmyy    A  value_of_A2
4   2  ddmmyy    B  value_of_B2
5   2  ddmmyy    C  value_of_C2
6   3  ddmmyy    A  value_of_A3
7   3  ddmmyy    B  value_of_B3
8   3  ddmmyy    C  value_of_C3
```

Comment: great, Can u tell me from question how you convert input values to dataframe? i.e. input to code

Comment: @VivekSable - obviously is used [`read_clipboard`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_clipboard.html)

Comment: @jezrael with `melt` I get error: `name 'id_vars' is not defined` and with the other option it just doesn't work. I get a message: `'list' object is not callable`

Comment: thanx. got it. what I was doing before that, copy Input from question and write in text file by separator and then use CSV to create input dataframe.

Comment: @TheDaJon - problem is with sample data too `df = pd.DataFrame({'TIME': {0: 'ddmmyy', 1: 'ddmmyy', 2: 'ddmmyy'}, 'A': {0: 'value_of_A1', 1: 'value_of_A2', 2: 'value_of_A3'}, 'B': {0: 'value_of_B1', 1: 'value_of_B2', 2: 'value_of_B3'}, 'ID': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3}, 'C': {0: 'value_of_C1', 1: 'value_of_C2', 2: 'value_of_C3'}})` ?

Comment: @VivekSable - yes, it is a bit complicated.

Comment: @TheDaJon - I think there is problem in some columns are lists in real data. Need convert them to tuples by `df['col'] = df['col'].apply(tuple)`. Then apply solution. Last if need `lists` again  `df['col'] = df['col'].apply(list)`

Comment: ok thank you for your help! you always saves me! though this time I used the second answer, it was a bit easier and seemes to work right away